# How to use a union along with two structs + more

Tags: c, struct, unions

I'm having trouble with my assignment and was hoping to get some help.

I'm suppose to have two structs, volunteer and employee, and a union 'person' that takes firstname, lastname, telenumber + either volunteer or employee as a struct.

I have had experience using unions + structs before, but I'm suppose to have additional information in the union. I was wondering how I can set it up properly, this is what I have so far.

```
typedef struct volunteer{
    int hours;
    int tasksCompleted;
}student;

typedef struct employee{
    float salary;
    int serviceYears;
    int level;
}employee;

typedef union person{
    char firstName[20];
    char familyName[20];
    char telephoneNum[10];
    //employee e;
    //volunteer;
}person;
```

Any help would be great. This is the task instruction I'm stuck on.

> Create a person record that consists of the common records: first name, family name and telephone and a union between the volunteer and employee record.   Make sure that you add a field to discriminate between the two records types employee or volunteer.

Comment: read the instruction: `union between the volunteer and employee record`

Comment: Anyone that says they have experience with unions before and then unions first name, last name and phone number should have all their code audited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overthinking this: you need a structure to represent person.  The key part is

> "and a union between the volunteer and employee record."

```
typedef enum { employee_person, volunteer_person }  person_type;
typedef struct person{
    char firstName[20];
    char familyName[20];
    char telephoneNum[10];
    person_type type;
    union {
        struct employee employee;
        struct volunteer volunteer;
    };
}person;
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to say.  Are you stating my original response was assuming employee && volunteer are typedef'd or that I should include the OP's struct definitions? (Thank you for pointing that oversight out btw!)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Was wondering how I can access the information correctly. I initilized with `person test = {"George", "Michaels","654456123", 10, 5000.22, 3};` and tried to access the gpa with `printf("The gpa is %d\n", test.s.gpa); ` and I'm receiving a memory address instead of the value.

Comment: @user1692517 According to your struct definition there is no field s or gpa, so I can't help with your exact problem.  I'm assuming you have a `student` definition with a field named `gpa` and is field `s`.  If you post your struct declarations and simplified example of the code somewhere I would be happy to help.  (PS if you found the answer helpful, please upvote ;).

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you ask:

```
typedef struct volunteer {
    int hours;
    int tasksCompleted;
} student;

typedef struct employee {
    float salary;
    int serviceYears;
    int level;
} employee;

struct person {
    char firstName[20];
    char familyName[20];
    char telephoneNum[10]; 
    bool is_employee;
    union {
        employee e;
        student s;
    } info;
} person;
```